# ng-options bound variable is not updated after clearing the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-options

I'm using an array to populate a list with `ng-options`, and a property binded to the selected item. After clearing the array, the bound variable `myObject.selectedItem` keeps the value of the last item selected.

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="myObject.selectedItem" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in myArrayList | orderBy:'Id'" required>
    <option value="">Select something</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.myArrayList = [ { Id: 1, Name: "Item 1" }, { Id: 2, Name: "Item 2" } ];
$scope.myObject = { selectedItem: null };
```

... after selecting *Item 2*:

```
$scope.myArrayList.length = 0;              // Clears the array
console.log($scope.myObject.selectedItem);  // Prints: 2
```

Is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value stored in `... .selectedItem` is saved, and is not bound to where the original value came from.

So yes, this is the normal and expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely normal behavior.

`ng-model` is a separate binding from the options rendered by the backing array. As a result, changing the source of `ng-options` has no effect on the `ng-model` bound property.

If you are emptying your array, you need to also set `myObject.selectedItem` to null after setting the backing array length.

If you intend on doing this type of operation often and want it to dynamically update `myObject.selectedItem`, you could always register a watcher on `myArrayList` and set `selectedItem` to null if the length updates to 0.